# You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error. the error is still showing after npm update and reinstall

Tags: angularjs

I have downloaded a Angular project from Github, and "ng serve" did not work. So, I removed the "node_modules" and "package-lock.json", then tried both "npm install and npm update", but the "ng serve" is still not working and have the error
 **"You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core". This is an error."**

Does anyone have any clue of what is going on here? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

when you download an Angular project from Github you should execute **npm install**

if you have already run npm install, make sur you have a correct path to run your Angular project
e.g :
root is your folder which contains your App
inside root you should have 4 folders  :

.vscode
e2e
node_modules
src

and anothors fils
.angular-cli
..